# Django - how to pass object to ModelForm via UpdateView?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this situation:

To edit the klient, `UpdateView` is used:

`url(r'^klient_change/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', KlientUpdateView.as_view(), name='url_klient_change'),`

Update View takes care of updating the object, it uses `KlientUpdateForm`

```
class KlientUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = KlientUpdateForm
    model = Klient
    template_name = 'forms/klient_zmenit.html'
```

The problem is, that I need to update existing object using my own save method, which gets `klient object` and does something more (my save method is not complete in this example, it does a lot more).

```
class KlientUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Klient

    # This method creates and saves a database object from the data bound to the form.
    def save(self):
        #self.cleaned_data obsahuje data z formulare
        data = self.cleaned_data
        klient = get_object_or_404(Klient, klient_id =self.request.pk)
        Klient.objects.filter(klient_id = self.request.pk).update(nazev=data['nazev'], telefon=data['telefon'],)

        return klient
```

How can I obtain particualr object having pk from URL in `modelForm`? Is it  possible to do this? `ModelForm` doesn't know anything about `request`. My idea was to get the object in `updateview` which is possible but i dont know, how to pass it to `save method` of that  `modelform`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `KlientUpdateForm.save`, your object should be available as `self.instance`.

Comment: Yes! You're right. `self.instance.pk` returns desired primary key!